# HTTP Error: 429, Quota exceeded for quota group 'ReadGroup'

Tags: firebase, google-apis-explorer, firebase-cli

I started to get following quota exceeded error

```
Error: HTTP Error: 429, Quota exceeded for quota group 'ReadGroup' and limit 'CLIENT_PROJECT-100s' of service 'cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:563584335***'.
```

when I tried to deploy functions using firebase-cli

```
firebase deploy --only functions --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

I changed the value of `FIREBASE_TOKEN` thinking that it might have expired. `deploy` worked for one time after changing token but then again cli tools again started giving above error. Also, I checked [quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) but couldn't find any value that exceed the quota limit. My project is on **blaze plan** (pay as you go).

Maybe I'm missing something? Could anyone help me out on when exactly this error comes and how to fix it?

Comment: I know this quest was specific to firebase but did you figure out what quota this is and if it can be increased?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem being addressed by the Firebase team.

In the future, when you have a problem deploying with the Firebase CLI, you should [file a bug report with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) so they can collect information.

Comment: Thanks Doug for the quick reply

Comment: Is there a current support ticket that can be tracked?

Comment: @jpunk11 No, you should contact Firebase support directly.

Comment: Is it possible to just increase the gcp quota causing this error?